# Always avoid using <iframe>?

Tags: google-maps, iframe

Some days ago, some friends of mine told me to avoid using `<iframe>` for virtually *anything*, which of course includes Google Maps. That made me do some research and, among other things, find this thread in Quora (http://www.quora.com/Google-Maps/What-are-best-practices-and-recommendations-to-implement-Google-maps-within-an-iframe-on-a-webpage), which I think isn't conclusive, at least in my case. I've made a simple site which includes displaying a Google Map. I used an `<iframe>` because it is very simple and, as pointed out before, it is the option that Google offers within every map, so I guessed it was the optimal one.

My question is: using an `<iframe>` is always a bad solution, or in a simple case like mine (only displaying a location map), is it recommended?

Thank you all, please let me hear your thoughts on this,
João

Comment: iframes are the only practical method of displaying another webpage embedded within yours, unless you want to set up a full proxying system. Even things like those fancy GUI editors you get in browsers these days are implemented via iframes, so that any CSS in the stuff you're editting doesn't contaminate the css of the page containing the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Using an `iframe` is like having another page loaded in your browser. Which takes resources. I think this is what the suggestion to avoid it based on. But naturally, the solution is to avoid those who suggest that you should avoid something *always*. Just use it when it makes sense and know where to stop.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I suspect that that "always" was said / written in the context of user interaction, which isn't the case of merely displaying a static map...